# Restkit equivalent of `[NSMutableURLRequest HTTPShouldHandleCookies]`

Tags: objective-c, macos, cookies, restkit, nsurlrequest

I have two pieces of software with a different approach:

1. using `NSMutableURLRequest`
2. using [RestKit](http://www.restkit.org)

In **1.** I have the following line:

```
request.HTTPShouldHandleCookies = NO;
```

Since "approach **1.**" works fine I am now looking for an equivalent for the approach using RestKit. I get the same behaviour when I **delete all the cookies** in the  `[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage]` like so:

```
NSHTTPCookieStorage *cookieStorage = [NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage];
for (NSHTTPCookie *cookie in cookieStorage.cookies)
{
    [cookieStorage deleteCookie:cookie];
}
```

However, this **deletes all the cookies system-wide** so I am signed out of the affected websites in my browser.

I am now looking for a way to get an equivalent of `HTTPShouldHandleCookies` with RestKit.

**Update**:

I am using RestKit like so:

```
[manager putObject: myObject path: path parameters:nil success:nil];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I now found a work-around to solve the problem**:

1. Delete the cookie from the store (save the cookie for later)
2. Issue the request using RestKit as normal
3. Re-add the cookie to the cookie store in any completion blocks

<sub>** However, any clean solutions are very welcome and will happily be marked as answer</sub>

These are the methods I used:

```
- (void) disableSessionCookie{
    NSHTTPCookieStorage *cookieStorage = [NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage];
    NSArray *cookiesToDelete = @[@"myspecial_session"];

    for (NSHTTPCookie *cookie in cookieStorage.cookies){
        if([cookie.domain rangeOfString:@"myspecialdomain"].location != NSNotFound){
            if([cookiesToDelete containsObject:cookie.name]){
                self.sessionCookie = cookie;
                [cookieStorage deleteCookie:cookie];
            }
        }
    }
}

- (void) enableSessionCookie{

    if(self.sessionCookie){
        [[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage] setCookie:self.sessionCookie];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `NSHTTPCookieStorage`, you can interrogate each cookie before you decide to delete it (using `domain` / `name`). In this way you can filter the deletions to only the domain you're interested in.

Using RestKit, you can use the `RKObjectManager` to create the `NSURLRequest` using `requestWithObject:method:path:parameters:` (or one of the related methods), and then you can modify the request and action it yourself (possibly using RestKit operations).

Comment: I am not using a request but `putObject` instead (see my updated answer). I wonder if there is a way to set this globally or per manager though. As a workaround I will try to re-add the deleted cookie so that after the request was issued I will be signed in again.